# D3js gauge graph

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js

I'm getting started with d3js http://d3js.org and all I need at the beginning is gauge icon.
It displays how many time of auction run out and in which state auction is. There will be more icons on page.
Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TdWtC/

First load is ok but I need help with update. On update both have to be updated background and pointer. The main problem is that on update background overlaps pointer.
Probably I'm doing it totally wrong but I customized similar snippet and cannot move on.

this is the part where background overlaps pointer

```
this.body.append("svg:path")
        .style("fill", color)
        .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(this.valueToRadians(start))
        .endAngle(this.valueToRadians(end))
        .innerRadius(0.4 * this.config.raduis)
        .outerRadius(this.config.raduis))
        .attr("transform", function() { return "translate(" + self.config.cx + ", " + self.config.cy + ") rotate(270)" });
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you the bands of the gauge aren't contained in their own `g` element. Any calls to update append the bands *after* the `g` element for the pointer, thus appearing on top of it. You can fix this easily by putting the bands into their own `g` element that is appended before the `g` for the pointer.

I've made these changes [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TdWtC/3/) and also d3ified your code a bit -- you don't need to pass the bands individually to d3, it can take care of drawing them all at the same time. Note that I'm only handling the `.enter()` selection (i.e. new elements) as you're not changing any data in the `update()` calls. To make it work for changed data, you'd need to implement a handler for the `.exit()` selection (remove elements, probably simply `segments.exit().remove()`) and the updated selection (probably the code you're using to set the start and end angles for the `.enter()` selection).

Comment: It helped with the overlapping. But can you help me with handling the update. I updated the fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/qQHTa/](http://jsfiddle.net/qQHTa/) with update data.