# How to create Gauge Needle code in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can we create a speed gauge needle using a javascript library such as D3.js.

Comment: What is the reason to raise question and ask yourself in 10 sec?

Comment: If you want to share your skills start your blog or write articles and notes for appropriate web sites. SO is the place for raising questions you face difficulties with and looking for useful answer that way be used in future. So what we have here - 1) Sure there is more then one way to reach the goal you described 2) There is no sense raise question if you already know answer 3) Your post may be a possible duplication of existing and already resolved one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421499/d3js-gauge-graph

Comment: I have found this implementation [http://bl.ocks.org/msqr/3202712](http://bl.ocks.org/msqr/3202712) Looks nice

Answer (score 3):

I have provided and easy implemenation of Gauge Needle in D3.js.
Looking forward for your comments and appreciation if you like.

http://jsfiddle.net/akashtyagi40/u28n234k/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style id="jsbin-css">
svg
{
margin-left: 30px;
margin-top: 30px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="D3line"></div>
<script id="jsbin-javascript">
var svg = d3.selectAll("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", 300)
.attr("height", 300);
//Path inner and outer radius is adjusted
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(30)
.outerRadius(120)
.startAngle(120 * (Math.PI/180))
.endAngle(240 * (Math.PI/180));

var plot = svg
.append("g")
.attr("class", "arc");

var image = svg.append("svg:image")
.attr('x',50)
.attr('y',0)
.attr('width', 200)
.attr('height', 240)
.attr("xlink:href","file:///D:/ATC%20Project/D3%20poc/Gauge%20Needle%20POC's/gauge_skin.jpg")
.attr("id", "fillImage")
.on("click", turnNeedle);

var needle = svg
.append("g")
.attr("class", "needle")
.attr("transform", "translate( 0 , 0 )")
.append("path")
.attr("class", "tri")
.attr("d", "M" + (300/2 + 2) + " " + (120 + 10) + " L" + 300/2 + " 0 L" + (300/2 - 3) + " " + (120 + 10) + " C" + (300/2 - 3) + " " + (120 + 20) + " " + (300/2 + 3) + " " + (120 + 20) + " " + (300/2 + 3) + " " + (120 + 10) + " Z")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-60, " + 300/2 + "," + (120 + 10) + ")");

function turnNeedle()
{
needle
.transition()
.duration(2000)
.attrTween("transform", tween);
function tween(d, i, a) {
console.log(d);
console.log(i);
console.log(a);
return d3.interpolateString("rotate(-60, 150, 130)", "rotate(60, 150, 130)");
}
}
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```